# How do I combine the benefits of ``parBuffer`` and ``parListChunk``?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have some Haskell code which involves doing a lot of mutually-non-overlapping things to a big (65.5k elements) list of items. This seemed like a good fit for parallelization, which I undertook using `Control.Parallel.Strategies.parBuffer`. This helped, but I'm convinced that the work is too fine-grained, and I would also like to process the list in chunks (as would be done by `Control.Parallel.Strategies.parListChunk`). However, because my list is large, experiments using *only* `parListChunk` did not gain as much speedup, as the entire 65-odd-thousand-item list had to be evaluated to make this work (as the memory use of the program showed).

Is there a way to write a `Strategy` that gives me the benefits of *both* `parBuffer` (i.e. the list is treated as a lazy buffer with a controllable amount of evaluation) and also `parListChunk` (i.e. the work is broken down into pieces consisting of several elements of the list instead of individuals). I'm not really sure how to do this.

Edit: As per request, here is what I am working with, complete with explanatory comments:

```
parBufferMap :: Int -> Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parBufferMap i strat f = withStrategy (parBuffer i strat) . fmap f

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let allTables = genAllTables 4 -- a list of 65.5k Tables               
  let results = parBufferMap 512 rdeepseq theNeedful allTables -- theNeedful is what I need to do to each Table, independently of each other
  let indexed = zip [1..] results
  let stringified = stringify <$> indexed -- make them pretty for output
  void . traverse putStrLn $ stringified -- actually print them
```

My goal is to replace the `results` computation as it is (using *only* `parBufferMap`) with something that combines the benefits of `parBufferMap` and `parListChunk`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doing a lot of mutually non-overlapping things"? Some code and/or pseudo-code would help.

Comment: @ErikR Added some code to (hopefully) show what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you wan to compute:

```
map theNeedful allTables
```

but you want to do the mapping in batches of 512 tables.

Does this look like it will work for you?

```
-- assuming:
theNeedful :: Table -> Result

nthreads = 4   -- number of threads to keep busy
allTables = ...
allBatches = chunksOf 512 allTables  -- from Data.List.Split

doBatch :: [Table] -> [Result]
doBatch tables = map theNeedful tables

results :: [Result]
results = concat $ withStrategy (parBuffer nthreads rdeepseq) (map doBatch allBatches)
...
```

In words:

1. Break up the tables into chunks of 512 tables each
2. map `doBatch` over all of the batches
3. perform `parBuffer` on that list of computations
4. `concat` the resulting list

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing - I was wondering if that kind of thing is necessary, instead of just combining ``Strategies``, I guess.